# Kafka Confluent S3 Connector "Failed to find class"

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying a simple quickstart example and I get:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to
>   find any class that implements Connector and which name matches
>   io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector, available connectors are:
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector,
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkConnector,
>   io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector,
>   io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceConnector,
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector,
>   io.confluent.connect.hdfs.tools.SchemaSourceConnector

This is a brand new VM running the latest Confluent Platform 3.2.0 installed via Debian apt package. I can see that it definitely is running CP 3.2.0. Why wouldn't the S3 connector class be available?

Not sure if this is related, but if I do:

```
ls -l /etc/ | grep kafka
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           4096 Apr  5 04:41 kafka
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           4096 Apr  5 04:39 kafka-connect-elasticsearch
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           4096 Apr  5 04:39 kafka-connect-hdfs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           4096 Apr  5 04:39 kafka-connect-jdbc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           4096 Apr  5 04:39 kafka-rest
```

The docs reference a kafka-connect-s3 directory that clearly doesn't exist in the installation.

I'm using the Open Source variant of the Confluent Platform but according to https://www.confluent.io/product/compare/, the open source version includes the Confluent Amazon S3 Connect connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a packaging error in 3.2.0 and is fixed in the latest Confluent version which as of today (May 17th, 2017) is 3.2.1

There is also a bug fix to the S3 Connector in the 3.2.1 version so it's better to use that version anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can download the zip or tar version from http://confluent.io

From there you'll find `kafka-connect-s3` in the `etc` and `share/java` directory.